# TFS 2015 Git Error: TF401036

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

I am getting this INTERMITTENT error cloning a Git repo hosted in TFS 2015:

```
Cloning into '//MyCompany/XXX/YYY/CP/git/MyProject'...
remote:
remote:                    fTfs
remote:                  fSSSSSSSs
remote:                fSSSSSSSSSS
remote: TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote: SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS
remote: SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS
remote: SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS
remote: SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS
remote: SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS
remote: SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS
remote: SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                FSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                  FSSSSSSs
remote:                    FSFs    (TM)
remote:
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote:
error: remote: TF401036: The pack '1eab1bf4e611bd641725ea15fe9fd11ec30f63ae.pack' does not exist.
RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Anyone have any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be lack of disk space on the server. The only clue on the client was a single user using TortoiseGit trying to do a push got a message about lack of disk space. Since their PC had plenty of space we had to infer the error was on the server. We checked and we were indeed almost out of space.

It would have been nice if the error had been reported through.

Comment: Yes It is disk problem in your tfsappservers